# CSS position: fixed doesn't show <nav> after re-placing it somewhere else in the html code

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

While trying to build a responsive menu for a mobile version, I've met a behavior which I can't understand and seek your advice on.

I've attached links to two codes, which are pretty much the same. The only difference is in the position of the nav which is opened on "Full Screen" `(width: 100vw; height:100vh;)` once the user clicks on the "open menu" button.

On the first version, when the user clicks the "Open Menu" button, the menu opens up clearly as you can see. The change I did on the second version was simply to take the entire nav part and place it inside the main attribute in the HTML code.

What I don't understand is the following: Why does it matter if the nav is placed inside  or anywhere else on the page for that matter?. When a user clicks the "open menu" button, the #overley css has attributes of `position: fixed` and `top: 0px;` Meaning, it should be fixed on top of the page, but on the second version, when clicking the menu button - nothing happens and the window which should be shown isn't shown. I've even placed `z-index` to make sure it isn't "hidden" or something.

As far as I understand, position: fixed with top:0px should be on top, and that doesn't happen on the second version for a reason I really don't understand, and would appreciate learning why it happens.

[First Version - Working (Menu Opens Up)](https://jsfiddle.net/camelico/shuvty6L/11/)

[Second Version - Not Working (Nothing happens when clicking the menu button)](https://jsfiddle.net/camelico/shuvty6L/10/)

Working Version Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style>
body {
  background: #87cc77;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
#overlay-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  top: 3em;
  padding: 26px 11px;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
#overlay-button span {
  height: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay-button span:before {
  top: -10px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay-button span:after {
  top: 10px;
}
#overlay-button span:before, #overlay-button span:after {
  height: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay-button:hover span, #overlay-button:hover span:before, #overlay-button:hover span:after {
  background: #333332;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button:hover span, input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span {
  background: transparent;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -7px);
}

#overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ec6451;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
}
#overlay.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#overlay ul li {
  padding: 1em;
}
#overlay ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#overlay ul li a:hover {
  color: #333332;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="overlay-input" />
<label for="overlay-input" id="overlay-button"><span></span></label>
<nav id="overlay">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
<main>
<div style="width:100px; height:200px; overflow:hidden">
Text
</div>
</main>
</html>
```

Second Version's Code (The version where menu doesn't open up):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style>
body {
  background: #87cc77;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
#overlay-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  top: 3em;
  padding: 26px 11px;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
#overlay-button span {
  height: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay-button span:before {
  top: -10px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay-button span:after {
  top: 10px;
}
#overlay-button span:before, #overlay-button span:after {
  height: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay-button:hover span, #overlay-button:hover span:before, #overlay-button:hover span:after {
  background: #333332;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button:hover span, input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span {
  background: transparent;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -7px);
}

#overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ec6451;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
}
#overlay.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#overlay ul li {
  padding: 1em;
}
#overlay ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#overlay ul li a:hover {
  color: #333332;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="overlay-input" />
<label for="overlay-input" id="overlay-button"><span></span></label>
</body>
<main>
<div style="width:100px; height:200px; overflow:hidden">
Text
</div>
<nav id="overlay">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>  
</main>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh boy oh boy... it's been a while since I've seen such a messy HTML code, both sample codes are hard to look at. I'm not sure how to explain since I wouldn't know how CSS would react when faced with poorly written HTML structure. Always remember to make sure that your elements are nested properly!

I've fixed code for you, but seriously... I really think should learn a bit more about writing basic HTML correctly, before trying anything too fancy like interactive button or (as question tagged) responsive-design.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style>
body {
  background: #87cc77;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
#overlay-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  top: 3em;
  padding: 26px 11px;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
#overlay-button span {
  height: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay-button span:before {
  top: -10px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay-button span:after {
  top: 10px;
}
#overlay-button span:before, #overlay-button span:after {
  height: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay-button:hover span, #overlay-button:hover span:before, #overlay-button:hover span:after {
  background: #333332;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button:hover span, input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span {
  background: transparent;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #overlay-button span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -7px);
}

#overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #ec6451;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
}
#overlay.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#overlay ul li {
  padding: 1em;
}
#overlay ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#overlay ul li a:hover {
  color: #333332;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + #overlay-button + main > #overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="overlay-input" />
<label for="overlay-input" id="overlay-button"><span></span></label>

<main>
    <div style="width:100px; height:200px; overflow:hidden">Text</div>
    <nav id="overlay">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm in the process of learning, and would be very helpful to know what was wrong, or try and explain my question in the first place regarding the fixed position and top:0 (why it didn't work in the second version).

Comment: explaining by text alone seemed hard, so... https://i.imgur.com/RezFJd3.jpg

Comment: Understood following your explanation. Thank you, and advise you to update the official answer so others will know as well.